# distcp s3 instance profile temporary credentials

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, distcp

I'm using distcp on my hadoop cluster in AWS. Now we are switching over to use IAM roles for the cluster nodes. A solution I was going to try was add in my own implementation of org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem that would be smarter like the AWS InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider and use the IMDS. However is there an available solution to make distcp work with the temporary security credentials? Looking at NativeS3FileSystem and the related classes, it looks like I will need to copy most of the code just to make the credentials lookup use IMDS.